# Read content type vnd.ms-excel in R

Tags: r, excel

I am making an api call in response to which I get:

```
Response [https://reports.appsflyer.com/reports/v5/installs/id1059669903_installs_2016-07-11_2016-07-12_KVCZP]
  Date: 2016-07-12 06:45
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application~/vnd.ms-excel~; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 64.7 kB
<BINARY BODY>
```

How do I read this in R?

This is how I made the api call:

```
installReports <- GET(url = installReportsUrl, path = installReportsPath)
print(installReports)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
result<-content(installReports,type='text/csv',col_names=T,col_types=NULL)
```

This will represent the `.csv` report as a data frame.

Hope this helps!